# Ubuntu 12.04 cursor changes

Tags: 12.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, laptop, cursor

I have a weird problem with my Ubuntu 12.04 dual screen setup (Toshiba laptop + one monitor).

After a while the cursor on one screen completely changes its shape (not every time). I don't really know how to describe it because it's always something else. Sometimes I get four or five vertical lines instead of a cursor, sometimes I can only see part of the cursor, etc, sometimes weird shade appears.

This only happens on one screen simultaneously. If I go to the other screen, the cursor appears to be fine but when I change screens, the cursor changes. I tried to do a screenshot but when I do, the cursor looks just fine.

I'm using Unity and Gnome 3 but the problem is on both desktop environments. Nothing is wrong with my screen though because I'm also using Windows and I don't have any problems there.

Comment: Yes, I'm using ATI graphics. I forgot to mention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem with ATI graphics (you didn't mention your graphics but I am assuming you have ATI graphics because of this).

As far as I know there is currently no solution to this problem. Don't worry though because it is harmless.